# History panel grey on Dreamweaver CS5

Tags: css, history, panel, dreamweaver, flash-cs5

When editing a file in Adobe Dreamweaver CS5, the history panel (SHIFT+F10) will be grey whenever you are not in "design" view.

Not a problem **unless** you are editing a file which has no design view, such as, a CSS file.

Anyone who knows a workaround to activate the history-panel without having to go into design view?

Comment: What does this have to do with programming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no workaround.

When you edit the source code in Code View, and then go back to the Design View, there will be a new entry in the History panel named `Edit Source`. The History panel has no awareness of individual edits made inside Code View.

Instead, in Code View you should simply use `CTRL + Z` (undo) and `CTRL + Y` (redo). If you want to undo many steps, simply hold down `CTRL + Z`. If you go too far, redo a few steps until it's how you want it.

Lastly, this has nothing to do with programming, so I voted to close.